# Intersection between two 3D surfaces

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I have two independent 3D shapes; one is a square and another is a cone.

Let's assume the cone lies inside the square. How can I find out that the surface of the cone touches the square's surface when I move the cone in any direction?

It will be helpful if anyone can suggest an algorithm to check whether the surface touches another shape.

I am working with MATLAB, but the underlying logic will be appreciated in any language will be appriciated.

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/367565-findout-surface-to-surface-intersection-between-two-3d-shapes

Comment: what's wrong with the solution from your link? and I guess the answer to your question is maths? do you expect us to provide you with a complete algorithm?

Comment: Not sure I follow...a square is a 2D shape; I suppose you mean a square placed somewhere in 3D space? And what do you mean by "cone"? Some people take that to mean a half-cone, like an ice cream cone. A mathematical cone, though, extends from -∞ to +∞ along its axis.

Comment: and are you interested in the shape and limits of the line of intersection between the two shapes? That's a well-known and very old piece of mathematics: the [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section).

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively easy solution, thanks to the fact that the truncated cone is a convex shape, and finding its AABB is not so hard.

First rotate space so that the cube become axis aligned (and the cone in arbitrary position). Then to find the AABB of the base, is suffices to get the maxima an minima of the coordinates, using the parametric equation, C + R cos t + R' sin t, where C is the position vector of the center, and R, R' two orthogonal radii. You find the limit angles by canceling the derivative.

After finding the extrema on the three coordinates, the global bounding box is the one that surrounds these six points plus the apex.

By comparing the AABB to the cube, you can tell what distance remains before a collision, in any direction.

[image]